# Layer a transparent <div> over .swf file. Should I use z-index or opacity, or something else?

Tags: css, flash

So, I have this animation that I want to run in the background of my website.

http://www.theartificialasylum.com/index3.html

I want to layer some divs over that animation containing images and texts etc. I have tried using `z-index` in the CSS file and different variations of uses of `opacity` to no avail.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? this is the best I seem to be able to achieve: http://www.theartificialasylum.com/adex.html

Comment: It would help if you could paste the relevant `.css` directly into your question, rather then making us look through the code. Would you mind putting that up here as well? You can add this to the original question by editing it (this is preferable to pasting it into the comments itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Chrome's developer tools, I added some text to the 102 div, gave it a class of "lawl", and used only this stylesheet and was able to accomplish what it sounds like you wanted:

```
body{
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #fff;
}

#flashContent { 
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.lawl {
    background: #023;
    opacity: .5;
}
```

[image: random text in an opacity-enabled div on your fancy background]

I'm not sure what the problem was. Maybe it's your strict doctype. (I only use transitional myself.) Maybe it's because you were applying too many things to the html tag.

I do recommend cleaning up your code a bit, using more semantic IDs, putting test text in your divs, and paring it down so that you only test a **few** variables/lines of code at a time to achieve what you want.

Also, saving damn IE opacity fixes for last until after you have everything else done.

Comment: Also, I apologize for my religious gibberish. ;)

Comment: I do apologise about not getting back earlier. I had an exam on an unrelated topic and had to drop all this stuff.. I dont have the stuff with me at the moment but I'll have a bash with the above code snippet, I think I might get away without the opacity anyway as I am only going to have images over the top and they will be 100% opaque. Kudos.

Comment: See that above code, can I put some opaque text inside the transparent one?
So solid text and transparent background?

I'll tidy up the code when I get the chance, I was just working out the bugs in IE/Chrome/firefox/safari.. 
So far I have the behaviour pretty stable across the four of them.
I'm normaly a java person so it's been a bit difficult to get my head around.

Comment: Java, oh man, it's been a while since I've dealt with that. I love higher level languages so much better.

You can put solid text in an opaque div, but you'd have to set the background-color using a CSS3 technique (using rgba notation) that I don't think is supported in IE, or you can use transparent PNGs as your background.

I don't think IE6 supports transparent PNGs... but use of 6 is less than 3% anyway.